# Customize required = true in knockout validation

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: Participant().FirstName />
```

Model:

```
self.FirstName = ko.observable(data === null ? "" : data.FirstName);
```

ViewModel:

```
ko.validation.init();
     self.ApplyValidations = function () {
                    var participant = new Participant(null);
      participant.FirstName.extend({
                        required: true
                    }),
```

The validation is not working, maybe because I already have 0 or "" passed in text fields.
Can anyone help me with customizing the required so that it avoids "" or 0 and validates the textbox?

Comment: Could you create a https://jsfiddle.net/? There are lots of missing bits in the question and it would help a lot having a running (and failing) example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your Model instead.

```
 self.FirstName = ko.observable(self.FirstName || "")
```

Comment: var Participant = function (data) {
            var self = this;
            self.FirstName = ko.observable(data === null ? "" : data.FirstName);

Hi @korgrue, I have my model this way. thanks